# Javascript Date keeps always 1 day less

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, momentjs, angular-resource

I have a piece of code where I'm using the moment.js library to construct a moment. Then I use that moment to construct a date. All is ok till there and I can see it in the browsers console also.

But when the data gets posted to the server via an angular resource, the date sent is always 1 day less !!

Code is as follows:

```js
var theMoment = new moment($scope.TransMadeOn, "DD-MM-YYYY");
$scope.transaction.TransMadeOn = theMoment.toDate();
```

And then I simply send save the transaction object using angular resource, everything else is ok, just the date sent to the server is 1 day less.

I tried using fiddler and the request being sent from the client is 1 day less !!

I saw in some other post that its a timezone issue but I can understand how to fix it, especially as I need to fix this ASAP.

Comment: I'm not going to tick my answer correct as yet, I will wait and if someone explain to me why this is happening. I give the correct mark to them.

Comment: Please show your code that sends the date to the server, and show an example of the string that's sent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.

I didn't exactly understand "why" it was happening but using the following code it got fixed

```js
var theMoment = moment.utc($scope.TransMadeOn, "DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Comment: Do you know what UTC is?